# WPF TextBox Bind

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, bind

I have a class called VoucherEntity, includes a Property named "Customer", a object of Class CustomerEntity, so I have bellow code,

```
<TextBox Height="23" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="124,48,174,0" Name="txt_customer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=Customer.Name}" />
```

in .cs file, I have bellow code

```
_voucher = new VoucherEntity();
this.DataContext = _voucher;
```

it means, at first, the Customer property is null, after clicked a button, I will give Customer property of _voucher a CustomerEntity object, then I hope the TextBox can display it immediately, but failed, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to except changes in your view you should notify the view about the changes.

So just implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `VoucherEntity` class and fire the `PropertyChanged` event after you set the Customer prop

```
public class VoucherEntity: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private CustomerEntity _customer;
    public CustomerEntity Customer
    {
        get {return _customer;}
        set
        {
            if (_customer != value)
            {
                _customer= value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Customer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's a way to solve my problem, but I don't want to do so, because it will pollutes my class, only WPF need these interface, I have another way, txt_customer.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();,it also can works, but I need to give a CustomerEntity object to the VoucherEntity object before I click the button to choose a Customer.